# C# Rules Engine w/Expression Tree with custom Rule

Tags: c#, expression-trees, rule-engine

I am looking to create a simple rules engine using expression trees starting from the example given here: https://www.psclistens.com/insight/blog/quickly-build-a-business-rules-engine-using-c-and-lambda-expression-trees/

In the example, the author constructs rules using the following code:

```
 // Create some rules using LINQ.ExpressionTypes for the comparison operators
 new Rule ( "Year", ExpressionType.GreaterThan, "2012"),
 new Rule ( "Make", ExpressionType.Equal, "El Diablo"),
 new Rule ( "Model", ExpressionType.Equal, "Torch" )
```

The Expressions used are simple comparison ops.  How might one, using this sample, create a rule along the lines of:

1. new Rule ( "Model", ExpressionType.IsIn, {"AB", "AC", "AD"} )
2. new Rule ( "Model", ExpressionType.Contains, "ContainedValue")
3. new Rule { "Model", ExpressionType.IsTrue, SomeFuncThatReturnsBool(Param))

Are any of the above possible given the example cited?

TIA

Comment: **ExpressionType** is a [built-in enum with a fixed set of members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressiontype); you can't add new ones. Also, one of the goals of the rule engine described in the article is the serialization/deserialization of the various rules; I'm not sure how you could go about serializing a function call with a parameter -- do you serialize the function with the parameter? the returned value?

Comment: But you could create your own `RuleType` enum, and use that to power your rule engine. Each `RuleType` could define a different expression tree; and you could compile together the various rules and invoke them.